# command for distinct gives only one selected key value, it does not provide whole document?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In mongodb, while I run command to get distinct record from collection, It returns only key value for each record, it does not provide whole record data.

Comment: What do you mean? Post examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of MongoDb :

> The distinct command returns returns a list of distinct values for the given key across a collection.

It does not return the whole object, it returns the list of distinct values. See the documentation [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct).

For more information please provide an example and explain in detail.

Comment: ya this is true, but i want whole document for that key ? is it possible by any way ?

Comment: As far as i know it is not possible with distinct keyword. You can do it by using map/reduce.